# How to change the text content of static block region wise

Tags: stores

I want to change the content of static block region wise. for e.g;-
Suppose I have text ‘Go to Home‘ for US version and if I select UK then it should be change to another text e.g. "Shop at home"  This should be customisable by region shop (e.g. different geographic storefronts have different messages.)
How can I do it please give me suggestions. 
Thank u in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create separate new block from the admin side for every region you wants.

[image]

Here you can see the listing of store view and you can create individual static block for each the store.

Comment: I have created stores but those are not working can u tell me the exact way?

Comment: Hi you can refer this link which will be help full for you: http://www.woolleydesign.net/2013/03/magento-mult-language-show-different-static-blocks-based-on-store-views/

Comment: Thank u very much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [CMS translate](https://github.com/miguelbalparda/MB_Translate/) extension to translate CMS/Block pages just like you translate any other content on your site. The text will be the one you input and will change per store view. The benefit is that you wont have to maintain several copies from the same page/block.